# Serving Angular PWA from Azure Web App (Linux) fails on missing .webmanifest

Tags: azure, kestrel-http-server, angular-pwa

There are number of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925062/angular-not-serving-manifest-webmanifest) about the same issue, but the solutions to those are specific to IIS: we are hosting in Azure Web App Linux instance and are using Kestrel (ASP.Net Core 3.1) as the web server.

After setting up Angular PWA and deploying a new release, the Angular client throws the following message;

> manifest.webmanifest:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Commonly this error is shown when the manifest.webmanifest cannot be loaded (the current version I am testing is the default file that was installed by Angular PWA so its content is unlikely to be the issue).  Also, when in Chrome Developer tools I review the file, it will show the content of my `index.html`.

Following instructions for IIS, I tried to find out how to serve the file using Kestrel.  [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266152/10340388) suggests the following (I also tried `application/json`):

```c
FileExtensionContentTypeProvider provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/manifest+json";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

How can we serve the Angular PWA from Azure Web Service (Linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same thread as Ben's answer, there is an [answer by Cezar Crintea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914166/10340388) which is ever so slightly different but I hadn't picked up on the difference.

The correct configuration is to use `UseSpaStaticFiles` since the manifest is served from the Angular static folder and not the ASP.Net static folder.

The configuration that is working for me:

```c
FileExtensionContentTypeProvider provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/json";

app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

I also noted a comment by Henric Rosvall:

> In .NET Core 5.0 it has been included in the default provider mappings, and trying to add it manually will cause exceptions since it's already there.